# Remove multiple words from String in one statement

Tags: java

I wish to purge the `http://` and `www.` parts of an URL String using one statement.

I am not after wizardly regex-solutions, I simply want to know if there is a way to replace (read: remove) both words in one single replace statement.

Dream scenario:

```
String url = "http://www.superfect.com";
String[] purge = {"http://", "www."};
url = url.replace(purge, "");
```

This does not run, however. How is this usually done in Java?

Comment: Why does it need to be in a single statement?

Comment: It doesn't need to, I just expected java to be modern enough to be able to process an array rather than looping/doing multiline replacements. String replacement and substitution is quite a common task, so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in a simple loop:

```
String purge[] = {"www.", "http://", "https://", "ftp://"};
String result = url;
for (int i = 0; i < purge.length; ++i)
{
    result = result.replace(purge[i], "");
}
```

Now, the `result` String is the one you want. As *codesalsa* pointed out and given the context of URL's, you might want to do it this way:

```
String purge[] = {"http://", "https://", "ftp://", "www."}; //order is important!
String result = url;
for (int i = 0; i < purge.length; ++i)
{
    if (result.startsWith(purge[i])
    {
        result = result.substring(purge[i].length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a startsWith check first... what if superfectwww.com.

Comment: @codesalsa: You are right. Initially, I didn't care about the exact situation. I just provided a way to batch replace all elements of an array. However, I added some nice code :).

Answer (score 7):

In a single line, with a single replacement action:

```
url = url.replaceAll("http://|www\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't offer a method for replacing more than one literal character sequence at a time.  Regular expressions could be used, to match both intended replacement targets in the same call.

Without regular expressions, you need to call `replace` once for each target.

```
url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("www.", "");
```

Comment: +1 for regular expression.  I would suggest adding a code fragment to show the replaceAll() approach.

Comment: @JustinKSU I would have, except the OP stated "I am not after wizardly regex-solutions".

Comment: And right you are in that. Too many things can be hacked together with an sufficiently funky regex, I just wanted to know what was available "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
url = url.replaceAll("http://(?:www\\.)?", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got already plenty of nice & working solutions written right here. I'm, however, kinda a fan of clean, easily-understandable code. There's nothing more wonderful than elegant one-command solution. Here you go. You're welcome!

```
public class Test {
        public static String parseDomainName(String url) {
            return (
                url.startsWith("http://www.") ? url.replaceFirst("http://www\\.", "") :
                    url.startsWith("http://") ? url.replaceFirst("http://", "") :
                        url.startsWith("www.") ? url.replaceFirst("www\\.", "") :
                            url
            );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseDomainName("http://www.google.com"));
        System.out.println(parseDomainName("http://google.com"));
        System.out.println(parseDomainName("www.google.com"));
        System.out.println(parseDomainName("google.com"));
        System.out.println(parseDomainName("http://misleading.www.com"));
    }
}
```

Alright, I'm just joking! But it's the single solution right here, which works in one command and doesn't use regular expressions (well, method replaceFirst() actually accepts only a regular expressions, but it'd be working on the same logic even with different method, which accepts only plain text string).

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445075/2709026) solution as it's the best compromise if you really want to avoid using regular expressions. This solution I've made is really just a joke and it'd be horrible to see it used somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
url = url.replace("http://www.", "");
```

Wouldn't that work?

Comment: It would, but in the list of URL's there are occurrences where the `www`-part is excluded, so I need to remove them separately.

Comment: OK. Why do you need exactly one statement?

Comment: I don't need to! Doing multiple, singular replacements on separate lines doesn't feel as lean as replacing by an Array.