# Javascript RegEx Remove Multiple words from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using Javascript. (*note there is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445022/remove-multiple-words-from-string-in-one-statement), but the OP requested Java, this is for Javascript*)

I'm trying to remove a list of words from an entire string without looping (preferably using Regular Expressions).

This is what I have so far, and it removes some of the words but not all of them. Can someone help identify what I'm doing wrong with my RegEx function?

```js
   //Remove all instances of the words in the array
  var removeUselessWords = function(txt) {

 var uselessWordsArray = 
        [
          "a", "at", "be", "can", "cant", "could", "couldnt", 
          "do", "does", "how", "i", "in", "is", "many", "much", "of", 
          "on", "or", "should", "shouldnt", "so", "such", "the", 
          "them", "they", "to", "us",  "we", "what", "who", "why", 
          "with", "wont", "would", "wouldnt", "you"
        ];
   
 var expStr = uselessWordsArray.join(" | ");
 return txt.replace(new RegExp(expStr, 'gi'), ' ');
  }

  var str = "The person is going on a walk in the park. The person told us to do what we need to do in the park";
  
  console.log(removeUselessWords(str));

//The result should be: "person going walk park. person told need park."
```

Comment: Get rid of the whitespace around `|` for starters.

Comment: If I do that, then the function removes all characters instead of words. (ie: "walk" would be  "wlk")

Comment: @Jared Smith, I retract my statement above, as RomanPerekhrest made use of your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three moments:

- join array items with `|` without side spaces
- enclose regex alternation group into parentheses `(...|...)`
- specify word boundary `\b` to match a separate words

```js
var removeUselessWords = function(txt) {
    var uselessWordsArray = 
        [
          "a", "at", "be", "can", "cant", "could", "couldnt", 
          "do", "does", "how", "i", "in", "is", "many", "much", "of", 
          "on", "or", "should", "shouldnt", "so", "such", "the", 
          "them", "they", "to", "us",  "we", "what", "who", "why", 
          "with", "wont", "would", "wouldnt", "you"
        ];
   
   var expStr = uselessWordsArray.join("|");
   return txt.replace(new RegExp('\\b(' + expStr + ')\\b', 'gi'), ' ')
                    .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
  }

var str = "The person is going on a walk in the park. The person told us to do what we need to do in the park";
  
console.log(removeUselessWords(str));
```

Comment: Wow. This works. Thank you. What does the `\\b` imply?

Comment: This is even better!

Comment: You'll also want to add a `.replace(/\s+\.(\s|$)/g, '.$1')` at the end of all of that to clean up potential spaces before periods.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you want:

```js
   //Remove all instances of the words in the array
  var removeUselessWords = function(txt) {

 var uselessWordsArray = 
        [
          "a", "at", "be", "can", "cant", "could", "couldnt", 
          "do", "does", "how", "i", "in", "is", "many", "much", "of", 
          "on", "or", "should", "shouldnt", "so", "such", "the", 
          "them", "they", "to", "us",  "we", "what", "who", "why", 
          "with", "wont", "would", "wouldnt", "you"
        ];
   
 var expStr = uselessWordsArray.join("\\b|\\b");
 return txt.replace(new RegExp(expStr, 'gi'), '').trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ');
  }

  var str = "The person is going on a walk in the park. The person told us to do what we need to do in the park";
  
  console.log(removeUselessWords(str));

//The result should be: "person going walk park. person told need park."
```